# Problems with accessing parameter Collection<> in parameterized jUnit 4 testing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit4

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {
private static final String FILENAME = "###############";
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    Scanner s = null;
    String line;
    String[] values;

    Collection<Object[]> check = Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{{0, new BigDecimal(0)}, {1, new BigDecimal(1)},{2, new BigDecimal(1)}});

    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File(FILENAME));
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            int i = 3;
            line = s.nextLine();
            values = line.split("\\s+");
            ((List<Object[]>) check).add(i, new Object[][]{{0, new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt(values[1]))}});

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 30);

    return check;
}
private int fInput;
private BigDecimal fExpected;

public FibonacciTest(int input, BigDecimal expected) {
    this.fInput = input;
    this.fExpected = expected;

}
@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.fib(fInput));
}
}
```

Hello, I am really new to JUnit testing and did a lot of research today. Accomplished a lot by my self and trial and arrow but I am stuck with a constant problem. I am trying to write a randomized test for dynamic Fibonacci calculation. The test is running with the base cases which are added by hand in the Collection check. They are working. I want to add more cases and they are controlled by a `.txt` file. The input is working, too but I am not able to add Objects to my collection later on. This is my approach but it throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationExeption in line 30:

```
((List<Object[]>) check).add(i, new Object[][]{{0, new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt(values[1]))}});
```

The casting was done by IntelliJ.
Tried a lot with different possibilities for collections and list but I am stuck here.

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `check` with `Arrays.asList()`. That `List` is based on the input array so it can not be extended.

One common approach would be to copy that list to an `ArrayList`, that will make it extendable.

so something like that:

```
Collection<Object[]> check = Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{{0, new BigDecimal(0)}, {1, new BigDecimal(1)},{2, new BigDecimal(1)}});
check = new ArrayList<Object[]>( check ); // copy to mutable ArrayList
```

To avoid the ugly/uncessary cast you can have check be of type `List`. `List` extends `Collection` so it is compatible that way.

Comment: Thank you very much! Added your suggestion and did some minor changes and now it is running!